# Is it possible to use statistics value as a build parameter?

Tags: teamcity

I'm adding build feature [VCS labeling](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/VCS+Labeling). Can I refer to [statistics values](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Custom+Chart#CustomChart-DefaultStatisticsValuesProvidedbyTeamCity) in labeling pattern? Something like

```
build-%system.build.number%-passed-%PassedTestCount%-failed-%FailedTestCount%
```

If not can I pass statistics values to build parameters somehow?

**Update**

For some reason REST API request

```
http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:$buildId/statistics/
```

doesn't return most of values during build. I had to use request for tests info. Here is powershell script:

```
$buildId=%teamcity.build.id%
$userId="%system.teamcity.auth.userId%"
$password="%system.teamcity.auth.password%"

$ApiCredentials_ForHeader = $userId + ":" + $password
$ApiCredentialsBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String(
    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ApiCredentials_ForHeader))
$ApiCredentialsHeader = @{}
$ApiCredentialsHeader.Add("Authorization", "Basic $ApiCredentialsBase64")

$testsUrl = "http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/testOccurrences?locator=build:(id:$buildId),count:10000"

$response = [xml](Invoke-WebRequest $testsUrl -Headers $ApiCredentialsHeader)

$PassedTestCount = @($response.testOccurrences.testOccurrence | ? { $_.status -eq "SUCCESS" }).count
$FailedTestCount = @($response.testOccurrences.testOccurrence | ? { $_.status -eq "FAILURE" }).count

Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='PassedTestCount' value='$PassedTestCount']"
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='FailedTestCount' value='$FailedTestCount']"
```

This solves my problem but doesn't answer question.

Answer (score 1):

If one of you build steps is a PowerShell(or another similar)script you can use TeamCity API to get statistics. Discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487902/getting-statistical-history-from-teamcity-api).